# CSS clouds animation issue

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm having trouble integrating this CSS clouds animation into my 
website. The `overflow: hidden` and `scroll` are causing my problems.
I don't want the clouds scrolling outside of the blue box background area, but don't know how . Please see http://www.filehostfree.com/cloudcsstest/cssanimation.html

I've left a comment in the source code.

Comment: Please add your code to the question (or) create a demo. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: also It doesn't seem to animate somehow in IE :( , works in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the *scrollbar* you have to add an `overflow-x: hidden;` into the container of the Clouds (`#clouds`).

Anyway I encourage you to avoid using `margin` or positioning properties (like `left`, `right`...) and use `transform: translate()` in animation to avoid *repaint* and gain in page performance.

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywxkb0zd/) I changed the `@keyframes` animation into

```
@keyframes moveclouds {
  0% { transform: translateX(1000px);}
  100% { transform: translateX(-1000px) }
}
```

Also have to add that you are using prefixed properties like:

```
-webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
-o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
```

but not the unprefixed one, that nowadays have so good crossbrowser support.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the scroll issue, this will remove the horizontal scroll.

```
.yourContainingDivClass { 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  position: absolute; 
}
```

Regarding why the clouds suddenly appear, you should add a negative X position at the beggining and at the end of the animation cycle:

```
@keyframes move_cloud {
  0% {
    left: 120%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -20%;
  }
}
```

You can play around with this [Pen](http://codepen.io/manuelro/pen/repEmo?editors=1100), if you want. It has been coded using SASS, therefore you can tweak the variables to meet your needs.

---

#### CSS3 animations and Internet Explorer (IE)

IE does not support CSS3 animations until IE10, therefore your animations will not render properly in any version of IE < 10. Checkout the [support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation).

#### Alternatives to CSS3

***HTML5 Canvas:***
HTML5 Canvas API offers a wider range of options to create this kind of animations. The performance is also better.

***Javascript:***
If you feel confortable using JavaScript, a good alternative would be to use [TweenJS](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/) to animate the CSS properties via [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), although the performance will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. Appreciated , the overflow-x: hidden; 
fixed the scroll issue, that was main issue, only other thing it don't work in IE but that don't bother me too much, chrome and firefox are fine, my site is working now